# PowerShell Test-path on modifed time

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script to Test if a certain file is currently in a directory and if so it will be used for the next action in the script. However this script will run on as a scheduled task and I don't want this step to occur more than once. In my head the best way to do this was to have the Test-path Command work something like this:

```
Test-Path C:\Path\File.zip | where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)}
```

This doesn't work as I intended in my head. Is there a way to check if a file is present and have that in an If statement? something like:

```
if(test-path C:\Path\File.zip | where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)}) {execute scriptblock}
```

Or if there is a way for Get-Childitem to return a bool in that if statement I could use that? Many thanks.

Comment: How *exactly* does it "not work as intended"? What result do you expect and how ist that different from the result you actually get?

Comment: Test-Path returns a *boolean*. Piping it to find LastWriteTime is meaningless. You have to use gci.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `Test-Path` cmdlet returns a `boolean` (`$True` or `$False`), not a `FileInfo` object. Thus, the return value does not have a `LastWriteTime` property which is why your code doesn't work.

You could, just as you wonder about, use the fact that if-statements in PowerShell considers empty lists and `$NULL` objects to evaluate to false while lists with items in or correct object references (non-null) evaluate to true. Thus you could just change it to:

```
if (Get-ChildItem C:\Path\File.zip | Where { $PSItem.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30))
{
    # File newer than half an hour exists
}
else 
{
    # No file newer than half an hour exists
}
```